# Showing $\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(2x)}{x^2+3}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-2\sqrt3}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Things are about to get real, prepare your mind!

---

$$f(z)=\frac{ze^{2iz}}{z^2+3}$$

Now this has two singular points, $\pm\sqrt3i$

$$f(z)=\frac{ze^{2iz}}{(z-(-\sqrt3i))(z-\sqrt3i)}$$ and hence both poles are of order $1$.

We can find $\operatorname{Res}_{z=\sqrt3i}f(z)=\frac{(\sqrt3i)e^{2i(\sqrt3i)}}{(\sqrt3i)+\sqrt3i}=e^{-2\sqrt3}/2$

Now I want to show that:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(2x)}{x^2+3}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-2\sqrt3}$$

Apparently this is pretty much immediate from my work above it, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first note that the integrand $\frac{x\sin 2x}{x^2+3}$ of the integral of interest $I$ is an even function around $x=0$.  Therefore we can write

$$I=\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin 2x}{x^2+3}$$

Next, let $C_R$ be a closed contour that is comprised of (i) that part of the real axis $|x|\le R$ and (ii) a semi-circle in the upper-half plane such that $|z|=R$ and $\text{Im}(z)>0$.  We then note that

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\text{Im}\left(\oint_{C_R} \frac{z\,e^{ i2z}}{z^2+3}dz\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin 2x}{x^2+3}dx+\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{|z|=R,\text{Im}(z)>0}\frac{z\,e^{ i2z}}{z^2+3}dz \tag 1$$

We can easily see that the limit of last integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$  vanishes by using [Jordan's Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JordansLemma.html).

Therefore, we have that

> $$\begin{align}
> \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I=\frac12\text{Im}\left(2\pi i\text{Res}\left(\frac{z\,e^{ i2z}}{z^2+3},z=i\sqrt{3}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-2\sqrt{3}}}
> \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the answer.  Remember from the Residue Theorem that

$$\text{Res}_{z=z_0}f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_Cf(z)\,dz.$$

Also you can use the fact that $e^{2iz}=\cos(2z)+i\sin(2z).$  Make this substitution into your $f(z)$ function and integrate.  Since your residue is real valued, the imaginary part of the integral is zero.

Comment: That substitution doesn't work since both the sine and cosine function are unbounded at $\infty$.  Rather, one needs to exploit $\sin 2z =\text{Im}(e^{i2z})$ and choose a closed contour in the upper-half plane.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by 'integrate.' Of course one needs a contour enclosing $z_0$ according to the Theorem.